# ksqlDb Unable to verify if the value schema for topic is compatible with ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I'm trying to create a new stream and topic with ksqlDb

```
CREATE STREAM valid_deals (
    dealId BIGINT KEY
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='valid_deals',
    PARTITIONS=4,
    REPLICAS=3,
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON_SR',
    VALUE_SCHEMA_ID=434
);
```

I'm using a value format from schema registry which is causing issues. When I run the above statement I get this error:

```
Unable to verify if the value schema for topic: valid_deals, schema id: 434 is compatible with ksqlDB.
Reason: Unsupported schema type org.everit.json.schema.EmptySchema
```

After which it logs the entire schema - I've run the printed schema through `org.everit.json.schema` to verify it's valid and it is indeed valid. So I truly don't believe this should be an issue with the schema itself.